# How do I separate/format string_agg() aggregated data using the *_id fields the data refers to?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, string-aggregation

This question is kind of a continuation of my previous question that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419155/how-do-i-remove-redundancy-from-this-database-layouts-1m-relationship-and-stil).

[This **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8107/2) is using the database structure & query that I am describing below.

The database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE artistnames (
    artistname_id       SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    artistname          TEXT    UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE artistalias (
    artistalias_id      SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    artistname_id       SERIAL  REFERENCES artistnames (artistname_id),
    artistalias         TEXT    UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE songs (
    song_id             SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    song                TEXT    NOT NULL,
    artistalias_id      SERIAL  REFERENCES artistalias (artistalias_id)
);
```

- one artist (table artistnames) can have zero, one or multiple aliases
- one alias (table artistalias) belongs to exactly one artist
- one song (table songs) has one or more artists (and is refering to the artist's alias he used to perform the song with)

Example:
Artist **Francis Veigar** also uses the aliases **Francis Fat** and **Francis Fighter**. One song **Song 1** has been released with the artist name **Francis Veigar**, for another song **Song 2** he was using the pseudonyme **Francis Fat** and a third song **Song 3** he sung using the alias **Francis Fighter**, together with another artist named **Peeka Boo**.

Using the query

```
SELECT
  string_agg(distinct(artistname), ' & ') AS artist_primary_name,
  string_agg(distinct(a1.artistalias), ' & ') AS performed_song_with_alias, 
  string_agg(a2.artistalias, ' & ') AS other_pseudonymes,
  song
FROM
  artistalias a1
  left JOIN artistalias a2 ON a2.artistname_id = a1.artistname_id
  left JOIN songs s ON s.artistalias_id = a1.artistalias_id
  left JOIN artistnames ON artistnames.artistname_id = a1.artistname_id
GROUP BY song;
```

displays the `other_pseudonymes` column like

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| artist_primary_name        | performed_song_with_alias   | other_pseudonymes                                                  | song   |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar             | Francis Veigar              | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter                     | Song 1 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar             | Francis Fat                 | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter                     | Song 2 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar & Peeka Boo | Francis Fighter & Peeka Boo | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter & Peeka Boo & Peeka | Song 3 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Peeka Boo                  | Peeka                       | Peeka Boo & Peeka                                                  | Song 4 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I would want it to look something like

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| artist_primary_name        | performed_song_with_alias   | other_pseudonymes                                                  | song   |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar             | Francis Veigar              | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter                     | Song 1 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar             | Francis Fat                 | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter                     | Song 2 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Francis Veigar & Peeka Boo | Francis Fighter & Peeka Boo | Francis Veigar & Francis Fat & Francis Fighter / Peeka Boo & Peeka | Song 3 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Peeka Boo                  | Peeka                       | Peeka Boo                                                          | Song 4 |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

separating the pseudonymes/aliases the two different artists are using by '/'. What has to be changed in the query to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery, then `SELECT` the aggregated elements and use `string_agg` again:

```
SELECT
  string_agg(distinct(artistname), ' & ') AS artist_primary_name,
  string_agg(distinct(a1.artistalias), ' & ') AS performed_song_with_alias, 
  string_agg(distinct(col),' / ') AS other_pseudonymes,
  song
FROM
  artistalias a1
  left JOIN artistalias a2 ON a2.artistname_id = a1.artistname_id
  left JOIN songs s ON s.artistalias_id = a1.artistalias_id
  left JOIN artistnames ON artistnames.artistname_id = a1.artistname_id
  left join 
(SELECT 
    string_agg(a2.artistalias, ' & ') as col,
    artistname_id 
 FROM artistalias a2
 GROUP BY artistname_id)
AS aggregated_aliases ON aggregated_aliases.artistname_id = artistnames.artistname_id
GROUP BY song;
```